# PHP connect to xampp failed

Tags: php, xampp

Heres my code in the php,

See as Text

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

    $con = mysqli_connect($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);
    $Email = $_POST['User_Email'];
    $Password = $_POST['User_Password'];
    $Full_Name = $_POST['User_Full_Name'];
    $CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM register_account WHERE User_Email='$Email'";
    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $CheckSQL));
    if (isset($check))
    {
        echo 'Email Already Exist, Please Enter Another Email.';
    }
    else
    {
        $Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO register_account values(User_Email,User_Password,User_Full_Name) values ('$Email','$Password','$Full_Name')";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $Sql_Query))
        {
            echo 'User Registration Successfully';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Something went wrong';
        }
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

and here's the error when i try to check it on my browser

```
Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\android\User-Registration.php on line 36

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\android\User-Registration.php on line
```

i've checked my db and codes as many times as i cant but seems like still didnt work forme. can anyone help me out please? thanks!

Comment: you define you `$con` variable in `if` statement and try to use it **OUTSIDE**.

Comment: this happens because you are creating connection and storing it to $con when it is post method and calling mysqli_close outside the if statement. it should not be giving error during post method

Comment: @MehranZamani what do you mean by outside? can you please show me how? thankyou!

Comment: @CarenGarcia  I think sabeerzabi's Answer is one of solutions you can take.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

    $con = mysqli_connect($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);

    $Email = $_POST['User_Email'];

    $Password = $_POST['User_Password'];

    $Full_Name = $_POST['User_Full_Name'];

    $CheckSQL = "SELECT * FROM register_account WHERE 
       User_Email='$Email'";

    $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $CheckSQL));

    if (isset($check)) {

        echo 'Email Already Exist, Please Enter Another Email.';

    } else {
        $Sql_Query = "INSERT INTO register_account 
      values(User_Email,User_Password,User_Full_Name) values 
     ('$Email','$Password','$Full_Name')";

        if (mysqli_query($con, $Sql_Query)) {
            echo 'User Registration Successfully';
        } else {
            echo 'Something went wrong';
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, check your code: you are only running `mysqli_connect` if a `POST` request occured, but you are running `mysqli_close` in every request

Comment: can you explain in a simple way and show me  if possible? im sorry im just new to this